# Grab abbreviations based on the number of capitalized characters preceding acronym

Tags: python, regex, text-parsing

I have a program that looks for acronyms in a paragraph and defines them based preceding words from the number of characters in the acronym. However, for acronyms that have words like `"in"` and `"and"` that aren't part of the acronym, my code has problems. Basically, I only want it to count preceding text if the word starts with a capital letter.

```
import re

s = "Too many people, but not All Awesome Dudes (AAD) only care about the  Initiative on Methods, Measurement, and Pain Assessment in Clinical  Trials (IMMPACT)."
allabbre = []

for match in re.finditer(r"\((.*?)\)", s):
 start_index = match.start()
 abbr = match.group(1)
 size = len(abbr)
 words = s[:start_index].split()[-size:]
 definition = " ".join(words)
 abbr_keywords = definition + " " + "(" + abbr + "}"
 pattern = '[A-Z]'

 if re.search(pattern, abbr):
     if abbr_keywords not in allabbre:
        allabbre.append(abbr_keywords)
     print(abbr_keywords)
```

**Current Output:**

````
All Awesome Dudes (AAD}
Measurement, and Pain Assessment in Clinical Trials (IMMPACT}

**Desired Output:**
```none
All Awesome Dudes (AAD}
Initiative on Methods, Measurement, and Pain Assessment in Clinical Trials (IMMPACT)
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import re

s = "Too many people, but not All Awesome Dudes (AAD) only care about the  Initiative on Methods, Measurement, and Pain Assessment in Clinical  Trials (IMMPACT)."
allabbre = []

for match in re.finditer(r"\((.*?)\)", s):
 start_index = match.start()
 abbr = match.group(1)
 size = len(abbr)
 words = s[:start_index].split()
 count=0
 for k,i in enumerate(words[::-1]):
  if i[0].isupper():count+=1
  if count==size:break
 words=words[-k-1:] 
 definition = " ".join(words)
 abbr_keywords = definition + " " + "(" + abbr + ")"
 pattern='[A-Z]'

 if re.search(pattern, abbr):
     if abbr_keywords not in allabbre:
        allabbre.append(abbr_keywords)
     print(abbr_keywords)
```

**Output:**

> All Awesome Dudes (AAD)
>
> Initiative on Methods, Measurement, and Pain Assessment in Clinical Trials (IMMPACT)

Answer (score 1):

My take on the problem:

```
txt = "Too many people, but not All Awesome Dudes (AAD) only care about the  Initiative on Methods, Measurement, and Pain Assessment in Clinical  Trials (IMMPACT)."

import re
from itertools import groupby

t = [list(g) if v else list(g)[::-1] for v, g in groupby(re.findall(r'\b[A-Z].+?\b', txt)[::-1], lambda k: k.upper() == k)]
for a, b in zip(t[::2], t[1::2]):
    abbr, meaning = a[0], b[len(b) - len(a[0]):len(b) - len(a[0]) + len(a[0])]
    if all(c1 == c2[0] for c1, c2 in zip(abbr, meaning)):
        print(' '.join(meaning),'(' + abbr + ')')
```

Prints:

```
Initiative Methods Measurement Pain Assessment Clinical Trials (IMMPACT)
All Awesome Dudes (AAD)
```